# jQuery is it Possible to bind() to the alert() event so I can bypass the default message box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want bind to an event but I am not sure if its possible. I have several coders on a project of which some use the standard alert() function. I want to catch that event when its fired off and display a jquery ui module. Is this even possible? I know I can go through and replace the alerts with a dialog() but i'd rather not sore through thousands of lines of code cross several files to do it if I don't have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alert` function does not fire an event, but you can override it:

```
//Save the old alert function if necessary
var savedAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(str){
  //Show dialog
}
```

This would have to run before any calls to `alert()`.

Comment: window.alert = function(msg){
} msg will give you the text passed.

Comment: you forgot to include the text parameter for the window.alert function.   it should be `window.alert = function(textmessage) {...}`

Comment: nice, thanks.. anyway to catch the text being displayed in the alerts originally fired off?

Comment: @chris Use `str` or `arguments[0]`.

Comment: @john your textmessage bit helped me figure my last question out, thank you sir. aepheus thanks for your original answer

Answer (score 1):

You could directly overwrite the `window.alert` method with one of your own functions that creates a jQuery UI Dialog instead. This would destroy the alert box for every other scenario, but you could cache it first in case you still wanted to use it.

```
var _alert = window.alert;
window.alert = function (message) {
   // create/show dialog
};
```